# Do complex polynomials form an orthonormal basis in the complex functional ($L^2$) space

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

> Let $D:=\{z\in C:|z|<1\}$ and consider polynomials $p_n:D\to C,p_n(z):=\sqrt{\frac{n+1}{\pi}}z^n,n\in N_0$.
> Is $\{p_n\}$ an orthonormal basis for $L^2(D)?$

It seems that they are orthonormal, but do they form a complete system? For real functions it is true, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Isn't $|z|-c$ orthogonal to each $p_n$ if $c=\frac I {m(D)}$ where $I$ is the integral of $|z|^{2}$ over D? ( m is two dimensional Lebesgue measure)

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy
It seems you're right, however i don't see the need for the constant. Seems that just $<p_n,|z|>=0$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy post it as an answer.

Comment: The constant is needed. $|Z|$ is not orthogonal to $p_0$.

Comment: The polynomials in $\overline z$ are missing. Are you familiar with the Stone-Weierstrass theorem? There is a caveat in extending the real version to the complex one. Here we have another manifestation of the same caveat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $c=\frac I {m(D)}$ where $I$ is the integral of $|z|^{2}$ over $D$. Then $|z|-c$ is orthogonal to each $p_n$ and hence the sequence is not a basis.